# How do I install node.js on Ubuntu 18.04 32 bit?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, 32-bit

I've scoured Stack Overflow and Google as well as other forums for this answer regarding Ubuntu 18.04 34 bit and the latest Node.js version. If it is possible could you please refer or provide me proper instructions on how to install Node.js on Ubuntu 18.04 or weather it is or is not possible to install Node.js on this particular 32 bit linux distro.

Comment: There are no longer official 32bit Linux builds for download. It may be possible to (cross-)compile a 32bit version yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much @Henry I will look this up now. If you have an resources you think would help accomplish that I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

node versions for 32bit systems are available at https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/

Comment: I checked the last one working on Ubuntu 32 bits is v13.0.1-rc.0 . With the versions above, I get core dumps while running npm to reinstall packages.

Answer (score 3):

You need to build from the source 
download source from the link

```
https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.9.0/node-v12.9.0.tar.gz
```

Extract and go to the directory , apply following commands to compile

```
./configure
make
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer this.I hope this works. In the case it does I will accept this as the answer ASAP, give me a little bit to try it out please.

Answer (score 2):

I know very late to the party. But let me tell you this I've Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and below is my system configuration

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS i686
Kernel: 4.15.0-109-generic
DE: GNOME 3.28.4
CPU: Pentium T4500
GPU: Intel Mobile 4 Series Chip
Total Memory: 3879MiB

as you know I run 32bit and I did try @ChauhanTs steps but it didn't work. Instead, I ran a few commands

```
$ sudo apt install nodejs
$ sudo apt install npm
```

and ran another command to verify the installation

```
$ nodejs --version
$ npm --version
```

it worked. Try this out and let me know if that helps.

Thanks
Ram