# it is posible to install nodejs version >=14 on linux 32bits?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, frontend

Im using a linux laptop 32bits and i wonder if there is a way to install nodejs version >=14 ?

Im trying to use React on VSCode and when i try to start a project it tells me i need Node 14 or higher

```
 saberx@saberx:~/Documents/react$ npx create-react-app miapp
 npx: installed 67 in 11.768s
 You are running Node 9.11.2.
 Create React App requires Node 14 or higher. 
 Please update your version of Node.
```

i searched on internet but cant find a way to install a higher version of nodeJs on my linux 32bits

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install node.js on Ubuntu 18.04 32 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57636893/how-do-i-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18-04-32-bit)

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59950869/9078341

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely, Node 10 [removed](https://github.com/nodejs/build/issues/885) offical linux x86 builds (32bit).

There were [unofficial/untested builds up to v12.16.2](https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.2/) but they ended there. I would guess they went from "unsupported" to "not possible".